# Enterprise network VS Industrial network

Tags: cisco, ip, ethernet, network

I would like to know the difference between the enterprise network and industrial Network.If someone has experience in industrial network, is he able to work in enterprise network?

Comment: Your question is totally opinion based question, Therefore question was edited according to rules in networkengineeringstackexchange.com

Comment: Network equipment sold as “industrial” often have components that continue to function in hostile environments.  They can have larger heat sinks and avoid using fans for cooling (making them more reliable in dusty environments). They can be rated to successfully operate in hotter environments.

Answer (score 3):

**Enterprise Network**

> An enterprise network is an enterprise's communications backbone that
>   helps connect computers and related devices across departments and
>   workgroup networks, facilitating insight and data accessibility. ...
>   An enterprise network is also known as a corporate network.

Most Networks available in manufacturing companies and offices use enterprise network and based on requirement network design can be different.

**Industrial network**

> Industrial networks can be defined as communication of data on a large
>   scale. They are made to cater to real time needs. Industrial networks
>   used in enterprises are known as enterprise networks or corporate
>   networks. They include LANs and WANs to transfer data between various
>   systems in a same building.

In industrial network specially focus for transferring data on large scale and additionally it can have different type of machinery such as scada systems, PLC system ...etc.  In addition to that industrial devices are made with different materials and high secured environment because these devices need to work in dusty, cold or high warm environment.

[More about industrial Network](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/industrial-network)